# Simple example of Masstransit with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, sample, masstransit

I want to use MassTransit bus with RabbitMQ. But I am not able to find a simple example. I am looking for example which will get me started.

**What I have tried.**

1. googled: But most the examples are using MSMQ or they using too many configuration options.
2. GitHub: I looked a the GitHub for MassTransit (https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/master/src/Samples) But the example here is heavily loaded. It's very hard to understand for beginners.
3. Reading docs: I have started reading docs but it will take some time before I finish it. I am hoping if someone shares a link to simple example which will get me started.

Please provide your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple, good pub-sub example using MassTransit and RabbitMQ both.
http://looselycoupledlabs.com/2014/06/masstransit-publish-subscribe-example/

In case the article link does not work, here's the link to the source code:
https://github.com/dprothero/MtPubSubExample

Thanks to the author of course!

Answer (score 1):

MassTransit implements a lot of concepts and provides great many features with a very small surface API. There's no simple way to describe everything it does, because the problems it helps to solve are not simple, but an example can be made small.

Have a look at this sample I have for testing throughput:
https://github.com/et1975/Throughput-Test

The only "extra" that one might find unnecessary is Dependency Injection integration. You'd want one in most cases, but it does hide how certain bits interact.

Look at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/masstransit-discuss for more help.

Cheers,
ET.